# a dynamic js table not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

this code for javascript not working.can any one help me with this.i've tried a lot but couldn't find out what's wrong here!!checked every line .i dont know if the code is wrong or there is any problem with my browser

```
<html>
<head>
<title>table dynamic</title>
<style>
tr{width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid black;}
td{height:33%;width:33%;padding:10px;}
.tableShape{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:centre;
    color:red;
}

table{border:1px solid black;padding:10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var i, j;
    var arr = new Array(3);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arr[i] = new Array(3);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

    function tabs() {
        var k, t;
        var m = document.createElement("table");
        m.setAttribute('class', "tableShape");

        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            var p = m.insertRow(k);
            for (t = 0; t < 3; t++) {
                var s = p.insertCell(t);
                s.innerHTML += arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    window.onLoad = tabs();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?  Put up a jsfiddle for us and we'll help you.

Comment: Please never use `new Array`. Just call `.push`. Or `var arr = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]` for your example. `x.setAttribute('class', y)` can just be `x.className = y`.

Comment: i don't know how to put js fiddle...

Comment: `window.onload` not `window.onLoad`?

Comment: Also, you need to bind your function reference not the result so `window.onload = tabs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to append your created element to the DOM:

```
function tabs() {
        var k, t;
        var m = document.createElement("table");
        m.setAttribute('class', "tableShape");

        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            var p = m.insertRow(k);
            for (t = 0; t < 3; t++) {
                var s = p.insertCell(t);
                s.innerHTML += arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        document.body.appendChild(m);
 }
```

Comment: Just use `document.body`…

Comment: Oh fine @minitech, if it'll make you happy. Personally, I like accessing the DOM one way but I know that my original version was uglier.

Answer (score 1):

When you create DOM elements in javascript, they are created in memory detached from DOM, to see them you have to append it to some node in DOM.

```
document.body.appendChild(m);
```

You are doing a nested operation using variables `k` and `t` so use it inside the loop

```
s.innerHTML+=arr[k][t];
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AmH22/1/